# Plural vs singular form of verb after set of plural and singular subjects

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I use verb in plural or singular form if the first subject in the row is singular but is followed by set of subjects in plural form:

> The story itself, the characters and their tempers make up/makes up a completely different utterance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the subjects are homogeneous, the predicate-subject agreement requires us to use a plural verb:

> As a general rule, use a plural verb with two or more subjects when they are connected by and.

You can read more about subject-verb agreement [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) or in many other sources online.

Comment: What do you mean by 'homogeneous' subjects?